# gps tracking on android

Tags: android, c++, qt, gps, tracking

I want to make and android gps tracking application that will track other gps devices.

I will write you some of my things that I want but you can tell me if this is possible.

1. I want to make application in QT ( does QT have libraries for
   connecting other gps devices
2. I want to use google maps ( if that is possible ) - so I can track
3. Is there any gps locator sdk? So I can buy device and connect it.
4. Can gps device send me some more information like fuel usage? For example I can make device that will read fuel usage and send me some sort of information to my server.
5. I need server for that? So I can only pay for some hosting? and maybe make php scripts that will handle me data?

That's probbably it, please respond so I can really see what is possible from all that.

Thank you.

Comment: And I hit return and posted the incomplete comment. I'll use the answer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) While there a way to run Qt apps on Android (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Necessitas), I expect it to be a world of pain, as is usually the case with ported frameworks. Plus, very few people are doing what you want to do, so the developer community is probably non-existent (so it would be hard to get help when you get stuck). I would go with "native" for Android Java code and libraries.

The rest of your questions assume you using Qt. If you go native, of course, you can use the Maps SDK, the Android location stuff, etc.

Comment: If you go with Java, it means you'll just be writing a normal Android app :) A good place to start is the official Android developer portal: http://developer.android.com/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't know what QT is. I'm assuming it's an app builder of some sort. Don't like 'em. Can't do any cool stuff with them. (That's a personal opinion. Ignore it if you want.)

2) There's no problem using maps in an Android app. See the add on library.

3) Most phones have GPS built in. Why buy an external one?

4) The GPS built in just provides your current location. Stand alone GPS units that can provide fuel information are querying an external database. I don't think they will share. Interfacing to their device for commercial use is very illegal. You could do it only if you are the only one ever going to use it.

5) The Google add ons library has a USB api. If you can design a device, you can talk to it. See 4 about fuel information.

You are going to have to learn how to program an app using Google Maps with GPS, learn the USB api, and find a device that you can electronically understand and can communicate via USB. Then you need to find a site that will allow you to interface with their fuel price database. (There's no way you can personally gather fuel prices nationally in a timely manner.)

You need to refine your specs after you program a basic Maps app that uses GPS. Then at least look at the USP api. Also, if you are looking into building your own electronics device, Google 'Arduino'. (Research USB interfaces with it. Out of the box, it uses an RS232 serial interface.)

Comment: Change USP api to USB api. (Sorry, finger twitch)

Comment: Qt is a cross platform framework that is used to write programs for all kind of devices. I want for example to put gps locator into a truck, so I can see where it is going. Second thing about the fuel, i dont need to use prices I nee some sort of instrument which will measure me the amount of gas that is pumping to the sngine. Something that can connect to gas pump. Is there any SDK available for makimg such a program?